# configuration for ufw to allow upnp between desktop and xbox360

Tags: firewall, streaming, ufw, upnp

I am really stuck with this question.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04
I cannot enable UFW to allow a connection between my desktop and Xbox 360 stream media when UFW is enbaled.
The connection and streaming works perfectly when UFW is disabled.
I know that the network IP address of my Xbox 360 is 192.168.0.20
I would appreciate it if someone could share the code I need to apply to enable streaming with UFW enabled.
I have reviewed UFW documentation etc and find the examples either confusingh or not relevant to my use case
Appreciate any helps that can be offered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to allow all traffic from xbox to pc.

```
sudo ufw enable    
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.20
```